XAMPP: after install php 8 MySQL shutdown unexpectedly INNODB warnings
Help.
I have installed xampp 3.2.2 for a long time with php 5.6, inside the xampp folder i have another folder with a php 7.4.3.
Today i put another folder with php 8.2.12, after putting the data in the folder i launched xampp-control.exe, it asked me the language and i confirmed. After i see that the old xampp mysql doesn't start anymore the mysql and it shows me the following log:
2024-11-28 11:50:50 1a9c InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2024-11-28 11:50:50 6812 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.

2024-11-28 11:50:50 6812 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2024-11-28 11:50:50 6812 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2024-11-28 11:50:50 6812 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2024-11-28 11:50:50 6812 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2024-11-28 11:50:50 6812 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2024-11-28 11:50:50 6812 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2024-11-28 11:50:50 6812 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2024-11-28 11:50:50 6812 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2024-11-28 11:50:50 6812 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: No valid checkpoint found.
InnoDB: A downgrade from MariaDB 10.2.2 or later is not supported.
InnoDB: If this error appears when you are creating an InnoDB database,
InnoDB: the problem may be that during an earlier attempt you managed
InnoDB: to create the InnoDB data files, but log file creation failed.
InnoDB: If that is the case, please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-creating-innodb.html
2024-11-28 11:50:50 6812 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2024-11-28 11:50:50 6812 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2024-11-28 11:50:50 6812 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2024-11-28 11:50:50 6812 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2024-11-28 11:50:50 6812 [ERROR] Aborting

Thank you

You say after putting the data in the folder What data into what folder?

Small Point XAMPP uses MariaDB now as denoted in this message InnoDB: A downgrade from MariaDB 10.2.2 or later is not supported. However, there was a MySQL V5.6 ! Are you getting confused between PHP and MySQL version numbers. And for that matter, confused between PHP, MySQL and mariaDB?
